# Call data binding adapter from code

Tags: android, android-webview, android-databinding

I am working on an Android app using data binding and I have to load an url into an `WebView`. I wrote a custom `BindingAdapter` and everything work perfect except for the case where the `WebView` fails to load the url. For this case I have an button which should call again that `BindingAdapter`, but I couldn't find a way to call it without initialising the `WebView` from code. So, my question is if it is possible to achieve this or if there is another way? 
Below you can find the `WebView` and the `BindingAdapter`

```
<WebView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:loadUrl="@{webViewModel.webViewUrl}"
      app:loadedCallback="@{webViewModel.loadedCallback}"
      android:visibility="@{webViewModel.error == null &amp;&amp; !webViewModel.loading ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}"/>
```

Binding adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter({"loadUrl", "loadedCallback"})
  public static void loadUrl(WebView webView, String url, Action<String> loadedCallback) {
    final String[] error = {null};
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      @Override
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        loadedCallback.call(error[0]);
      }

      @Override
      public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        error[0] = description;
      }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(url);
  }
```

Comment: You can set an `id` to your `WebView`, access the `WebView` in your `MyBinding.myWebView` (notice that an `id` for example `my_web_view` will be converted to `myWebView`) and pass this as a parameter. Have you tried that already? Or is your `Button` in another place..?

Comment: In big parts this is the solution that I find in the end. I'll post an answer with it and see maybe someone else has better idea.